# Ruby. Set default picture for CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I want to add default picture to my posts.

I have in my `app/assets/images/default/no-photo-wide.png` photo.

And my uploader:

```
class PictureUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
  include CarrierWave::MiniMagick

  process resize_to_limit: [600, 300]

  storage :file

  def default_url
    ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path("default/no-photo-wide.png")
  end

  def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end

  def extension_white_list
    %w(jpg jpeg gif png)
  end
end
```

But my tests:

```
it 'will add default picture if no picture is uploaded' do
      new_post = Post.new(content: 'some content', theme: 'some theme', user_id: User.first.id)
      new_post.save(validate: false)

      expect(Post.first.picture).to eq ".../no-photo-wide.png"
end
```

But in return tests are failing and when I view what result test gave me it told me that picture field is empty `picture: nil`

I've tried to do:

```
def default_url(*args)
    "default/no-photo-wide.png"
end
```

But it still don't work, can you tell me what causing this problem?

Comment: Why not set it as default field value on migration?

Comment: It was so long ago, when I asked this question :) As I remember, if CarrierWave have default method, why don't use it, right?) But thnx for advise :)